# Python3: Threading, kill thread and all children

Tags: python, multithreading

I am creating a program which gets some scripts or programmes (let's call it `script B`) in some kind of message queue and then starts a `thread A` to process each script.

Because there can occur many errors in these `script B` (and I don't have influence), it would be nice if could kill my `thread A` with all its children. I know the common way is to create a stopflag and then `thread A` controls this flag in some cycle to stop.

But maybe the input scripts are blocking (the reason could be a permanent loop), so `thread A` can not control the flag. Then I like to kill `thread A` (and all its children) form the parent. I don't care about information loss.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Create a subprocess instead of a thread. Killing a subprocess also kills all associated threads. And it is easy to do and safier (at the cost of memory of course). On the other hand even if you are able to kill a thread, deducing which threads are children will be way too hard and most likely OS dependent (if possible).

Comment: I think that's a good idea, thanks!